# jQuery Mobile frosted header

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm using fixed headers in jQuery Mobile. I can easily create a transparent header by using e.g.:

```
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
```

As the page moves up and under the header, it can be seen through the header.

What I want is to blur the page as its seen through the header, i.e. the "frosted glass" effect.

Just putting, e.g.:

```
filter:blur(5px);
```

into the header, blurs everything *in* the header, but does not blur what is seen *through* the header. I don't want to blur what is in the header.

Is there a simple one-liner or so, to obtain a frosted glass header in jQuery Mobile? It would be great if it was as simple as e.g.:

```
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), blur(5px);
```

Comment: You could create another div underneath the header to contain the frosted glass effect.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear in my original question. I've edited it to reflect that blurring the content *in* the header is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Create a second div as an header content and blur it as much as you want.

```css
.header {
  background-color: rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.8);
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}
.header-content {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
  -moz-filter: blur(1px);
  -o-filter: blur(1px);
  -ms-filter: blur(1px);
  filter: blur(1px);
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="header-content">Test test test test test test test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/m5u7u28d/)

css

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
header:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

html

```
<header>this is header</header>
```